# Redux Observables: Separate epics for same actions but different filters?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-observable

I'm new to redux observables: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable

I have a simple use case where I want to do 2 different things based on the user's `signedIn` state.

1. If signed in, add rsvp
2. If not signed in, show sign in modal

I have this in my `app/redux/epics/addRSVP.js` file:

```
import 'rxjs';
import * as scheduleActions from '../ducks/schedule';

export default function searchUsers(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(scheduleActions.ADD_RSVP)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .map(action => scheduleActions.rsvpAdded(action.payload));
};
```

My question is, should I be creating another `app/redux/epics/preventRSVPIfNotSignedIn.js` epic for the signed out use case? Something like:

```
import 'rxjs';
import * as authenticationActions from '../ducks/authentication';

export default function searchUsers(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(scheduleActions.ADD_RSVP)
    .filter(() => !store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .map(action => authenticationActions.show());
};
```

or is there a way I can put both in the same file? I feel like it would end up being a lot of epics if it's the former. Would be great to know what the general convention is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unsure, always create separate epics. It is easier to test and change later. Plus, there is little to no downside of this approach (performance-wise). Combining two epics is kind of adding an abstraction without knowing if it is really necessary.

Also, by the <s>looks</s> ducks of it, the domain of those two (side) effects are different. I would say this is a strong indicator that using separate epics is a good idea here and will be more future proof.

That said, if you're certain that your epic will not change or get more complex (currently if/else), I guess it is fine too.

---

After taking a second look, I guess what you want to do is "if the user is not logged in, show im a login page and wait until (s)he is logged in and after a successful login fire the RSVP action". If this is your use case, you might want to look into [`delayWhen`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delaywhen.html). This could potentially be even a better solution, but it's more of an advanced feature of RxJS. Maybe this is a good task for refactoring when you're more comfortable with `redux-observables` :)

Answer (score 4):

Sebastian gave great advice, and generally I would split them up and duplicate the logic. However, if you really do this a lot, you can create your own abstractions so you don't need to repeat yourself.

You could either create a helper like `requireAuth` that takes your expected action and an epic that is only supposed to receive those actions when they have valid auth. It would then return a new epic that wraps it.

```js
// Helper to abstract the common auth requirement checks
// which will also dispatch authenticationActions.show()
// when they attempt to do something they can't
const requireAuth = (type, epic) => (action$, store) => {
  // matching actions which they have permission for
  const valid$ = action$
    .ofType(type)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn);

  // matching actions they do NOT have permission for
  const invalid$ = action$
    .ofType(type)
    .filter(() => !store.getState().user.signedIn);

  return Observable.merge(
    epic(valid$, store),
    invalid$.map(action => authenticationActions.show())
  );
};

const searchUsersEpic = requireAuth(scheduleActions.ADD_RSVP, (action$, store) =>
  action$.map(action => scheduleActions.rsvpAdded(action.payload))
);

// You can then use requireAuth for any epics that require it
// as an example:
const searchMoviesEpic = requireAuth(scheduleActions.SEARCH_MOVIE, (action$, store) =>
  action$.mergeMap(action =>
    ajax(`/search/for/the/movie/${action.id}`)
      .map(resp => scheduleActions.searchMoviesFulfilled(resp))
  )
);
```

Adjust as needed--but be careful, adding abstractions can make your codebase hard to reason later or introduce bugs when someone later adjusts the abstractions without realizing how it impacts other codepaths. Testing becomes more important!